# Docker containers are running but commands are not working

Tags: 20.04, docker

I have a bunch of docker containers running on ubuntu server 20.04.2. All these containers are running fine. However, I just noticed that docker is no longer responding to basic commands. For example, `docker ps` hangs without any output. Similarly, `docker run hello-world` hangs without any output. My guess is that some update broke things. Is this a known problem? Any advice on how to fix it?